# Can anyone decipher this (1)?

Tags: meaning, character-identification

The following is what I found on the door of a shop. I can recognize some of them but not all of them. I think the first four are 國舅手執陰陽板、湘子瑤池品玉簫, the fourth one is 品玉簫, and the sixth 長生酒.

[image]

Comment: This kind of compound word is not officially recognized, nor is it used by the people. You can think of it as a kind of artistic creation, and no one can understand it except the designer himself. There's no need to try to understand the words, it's not the right word, it's like you modify many letters to form one letter.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar [here](https://hznews.hangzhou.com.cn/shehui/content/2013-01/23/content_4575879.htm)

[image]

> 國舅手執陰陽板，拐李先生法道高

> 湘子雲中品玉簫，鍾離磐石把扇搖

> 仙姑敬奉長生酒，洞賓背劍清風客

> 釆和花籃獻蟠桃，果老騎驢樂逍遙

Everything is almost identical except in the third group "雲中" is changed to "瑤池", in the fifth group "仙" is written as "僊", and in the seventh group "釆和花籃" is changed to "藍採背山"

仙-->僊 and 釆 -->採 are both wrong words

Comment: Where do you see 藍採背山? I don't see it.