# Can anyone decipher this (2)?

Tags: meaning, character-identification

Is this one read from right-to-left or left-to-right? I can't tell. Is the rightmost one 八卦穿衣 or 穿衣八卦？ Either way, it doesn't make sense to me. Is the leftmost one 富貴開運 or 開富貴運? Each individual ideogram seems to make some sense but when putting the whole thing together, I can't make any sense out of it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

開貴富運 (開富貴運)

祝壽仙座

度化生民 (渡化生民)

點石化金 (點石成金) -- It proves it is reading from left to right

到此蘆胡 (到此葫蘆)

手執幫筒

夫作官

八卦穿衣

Comment: Unlike [the other one](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/54252/can-anyone-decipher-this-1), this one doesn't really make much sense.